# Use select2 to simply prepopulate select from Ajax data

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I'm just trying to load the data for a select2 dropdown using Ajax, instead of putting the large dataset inline in my HTML.

```
$('input[name="field"]').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        results: function(data,page)
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

This works, in that it waits until I "open" my select2 list before making the Ajax call to get the data.  It then also displays the data correctly.  However, it isn't filtering the list as I type.  Instead, it makes repeated ajax calls to (presumably) get the filtered data.

Also, if I set an existing value in my form, it doesn't appear in my select2 control.  I'm guessing this is because I'm not using `initSelection` but I'm not clear on how to do this correctly.

Am I doing this all wrong?  It appears that what I really want is the functionality of `data` but with remote loading.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is ideal, but it works:

```
$.get("/data.json", function(data)
{
    $('input[name="field"]').select2({
        data: data,
    });
});
```

Comment: it's working but what json should be there in data . i mean in what form?

Comment: @KaranDatwani It needs to be an array of `{ id: 123, text: 'abcd' }`